# R - ggplot2 negative y-values error in swimmer plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Are negative y-values possible in swimmer plot (ggplot2) package? When there are negative values it appears to shift the entire axis so it does not line up properly and the data is skewed. Any tips on how to fix this are much appreciated!

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(study_id = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1","ID1"),
                   start_yr = c(-2.3,0,0.05,1.14), end_yr = c(0,0.05,1.14,1.24),
                   treatment = c("S", "S+S", "S+Z+S", "Z+S"))

swimmer_plot(df=df,id='study_id',
start="start_yr",
end="end_yr", name_fill="treatment", width=0.85, color=NA) + 
coord_flip(clip = 'off', ylim = c(-3, 5)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-3,5,by=0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

On reading your question, the first question to myself was: "What is a swimmer plot"? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swimplot/vignettes/Introduction.to.swimplot.html helped me understand that it visualises changes of data over time. It always starts at zero. This should answer your question - the swim plot package does not allow negative values. But you can of course trick around a bit. See below - comments in code.

```r
library(swimplot)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1"),
  start_yr = c(-2.3, 0, 0.05, 1.14), end_yr = c(0, 0.05, 1.14, 1.24),
  treatment = c("S", "S+S", "S+Z+S", "Z+S")
)

## first add 2.3 years to your start and endyear
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("_yr"), ~ . + 2.3))

## now you can just use "end_yr"
swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "treatment", width = 0.85, color = NA
) +
  ## add a custom labeller function to subtract 2.3 years from your actual values
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x - 2.3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>